How do I populate empty cells with different values depending on what category the empty cells are in?
I need to fill the blank cells in column C with the number that is already there for each ITEM NUMBER. For example for ITEM NUMBER 19951034,  there should be a value of 222,434 in column C for each cell. For ITEM NUMBER 4562, there should be a value of 23,543 in column C for each cell.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.



A
ITEM NUMBER
C




22/10/2024
19951034



29/10/2024
19951034



29/10/2024
19951034



13/11/2024
19951034



15/11/2024
19951034
222,434


27/09/2024
623222
81,052


10/12/2024
623222



16/12/2024
623222



20/12/2024
623222



31/10/2024
4562



27/11/2024
4562
23,543


28/11/2024
4562



29/11/2024
4562



29/11/2024
4562





Not sure how one would do this without using a formula, however, using a formula applied to an adjacent column, can be accomplished as is:


• Formula used in cell D2
=AGGREGATE(15,7,$C$2:$C$15/((B2=B$2:B$15)*(C$2:C$15<>"")),ROW($A$1))


Once the formula is applied for the entire data, one can copy and paste as values, lastly remove the Column C to keep only the desired column.

• Or can use MAX() function:
=MAX((B2=$B$2:$B$15)*($C$2:$C$15<>"")*C$2:C$15)


